# How Should I Store A Value for a Rails Application Which Changes Periodically but Needs To Be Accessible to All Users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global-variables

I have an API only application built in Rails, which requires an encrypted login to receive a token. Subsequently, requests for data from the API are authenticated with the token value in the header of the request.

I have another Rails application which uses this API for a few different things. Currently I have it set up to authenticate before making any request, which gets a token for that request.

This is fine, except that it sets up a potential race condition once the application is available to the public. It's possible that two requests could come in at virtually the same time, resetting the token twice, making one of the subsequent requests for data us a token that is no longer valid.

I wanted to use a $global variable to store the token and the date/time it was refreshed so that it's always available to all users and only refreshes the token if it is more than a couple of hours old.

This would solve the race condition problem, but from everything I am reading USING GLOBAL VARIABLES IN RAILS IS BAD. It seems to me this use case is an exception, but I want to do it the right way.

Is my only option to store these values in my own database? It seems silly to set up a data model for a table that will only ever contain two columns and two rows, but I don't know if that is the Rails Way(TM) or the Best Way.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: More than one user is using the same token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Rails' cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) to do that. It gets stored in memory, or in a volatile database such as Redis. You could have something like:

```
def a_cool_token
  Rails.cache.fetch("a_cool_token", expires_in: 2.hours.to_i) do
    a_method_to_regenerate_a_cool_token
  end
end
```

What will happen is:

1. When using `a_cool_token` to pass it to a request it will try to fetch it from cache;
2. In case that cache key is expired or undefined it returns `a_method_to_regenerate_a_cool_token`;
3. When the time set on `expires_in` passes the key becomes invalid.

You can always use a more statefull cache key, using some database query to build it, like:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("a_cool_token/#{some_timestamp_that_gets_updated_with_a_cool_token}", expires_in: 2.hours.to_i)
```

Implementing `def some_timestamp_that_gets_updated_with_a_cool_token` could retrieve when the token was last updated, avoiding stale responses if something else changes the token outside `a_cool_token`

I hope this helps to point you into a "good" solution.

Comment: Nice. Out of curiosity, is that `to_i` needed on `2.hours`?

Comment: `expires_in` should be an integer of seconds :)

Comment: So, I've been doing, for example, `expires in 10.minutes` (no `to_i`). And it seems to work. But, that's incorrect?

Comment: I like this solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jvillian it depends on the lib that does the interface with the database, some doesn't support non-integer values.

Comment: Ah! Great to know. Thank you.